# Help with in-App Purchase timeout

Tags: iphone, ipad, network-programming, in-app-purchase, connectivity

I've designed my In-App purchase to work perfectly thanks to the well-written in-App Purchase Programming Guide.  Unfortunately, I have run into one last snag.  My app runs entirely offline except for this one purchase - so I'm hoping there's a simple solution without having to implement tons of net code.

Basically, if I try to connect to make an in-App purchase with a device that is not connected to the internet, the timeout is ridiculously long (5+ minutes) on the SKProductsRequest.  My app is a free demo app, with only one purchase, so allowing the purchase to occur in the background is not ideal, as the user would be stuck in the app with limited functionality while they wait for the timeout explanation that they have no network connection.

Is there any easy way to test if the App Store is available on the device?  [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments] does not help here.  The code solutions I have seen have been extremely complicated.

Ideally, I would want to check this when a user enters the buy-demo screen and I would pop up an alertview saying no network is available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use Apple's Reachability Classes to check for general internet connectivity and only allow the button if there is WWAN/WLAN connection available.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html